# Why isn't my background image working in css?

Tags: html, css

Why isn't background-image working? I copied the relative path directly from my image.

```
 h2 {
     font-style: italic;
     border-bottom: 1px;
     font-weight: normal;
     margin-bottom: 0px;
     background-image: url("images/logo.jpg");
     background-repeat: no-repeat;
     background-position: top left;
     padding-right:10px
}
 .lead {
     border-style: solid;
     border-width: 5px;
     background-image: url("images/background.jpg");
     /* I cannot get the background image to print */
     background-size: contain;
     background-repeat: no-repeat;
}
```

Comment: What does your browser's web-inspector say? Does the request for `images/logo.png` fail? Is the `<h2>` element hidden or have styles overridden elsewhere?

Comment: Note that `images/logo.png` is relative to the location of the CSS file and not relative to the web-page or the site-root.

Comment: add your html too please

Answer (score 1):

You need to have content in your `<h2>`. If your image is the content (meaning your `<h2>` is empty), then add a `height` property to your div that contains your image.

***Example 1: (With Content)***

```css
h2 {
     font-style: italic;
     border-bottom: 3px;
     font-weight: normal;
     margin-bottom: 0px;
     background-image: url("http://lorempixel.com/400/200/");
     background-repeat: no-repeat;
     background-position: top left;
}
```

```html
<h2>test</h2>
```

***Example 2: (Without Content, Add Height)***

```css
h2 {
     font-style: italic;
     border-bottom: 3px;
     font-weight: normal;
     margin-bottom: 0px;
     background-image: url("http://lorempixel.com/g/400/200/");
     background-repeat: no-repeat;
     background-position: top left;
     height: 100px;
}
```

```html
<h2></h2>
```

Answer (score 1):

Share your Path or Folder Structure..
If Your Image Folder is Outside HTML CSS folder then try URL as

```
('./images/logo.png')
```

**OR**
Better make another div and give it background image.

```
<div class="Header">             
  <h2>News</h2>             
</div>
```

```
.Header h2 {
     font-style: italic;
     border-bottom: 3px;
     font-weight: normal;
     margin-bottom: 0px;
     height: 100%;
     width: 100%;
     background-image: url("images/logo.png");
     background-repeat: no-repeat;
     background-position: top left;
}
```

Comment: Why would it be better do add a div here? In my opinion this is unnecessary.

Comment: Yes! But for clearity and If , beginners am saying , And that's why Mentioned "OR" there:) .

Answer (score 0):

Just change the path to:

```
background-image: url("../../images/logo.png");
```

or for more safety use the editor that can validate the link like Brackets or Visual Studio.

Have a good day :)